# After opening port with ufw, nmap output shows port as closed

Tags: networking, email, dns, port, smtp

I'm trying to receive SMTP messages on port 25 (this is where my MDA server lives). I've opened port 25 on my box

```
sudo ufw allow 25
```

with this output:

```
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
```

But when I nmap the domain:

```
nmap -p 25 <my-domain>
```

I get this output:

```
Host is up (0.098s latency).
rDNS record for <remote-ip>: hostname
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
25/tcp closed smtp
```

Why is port 25 closed after I explicitly opened it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In nmap, a closed port means that the port is reachable, but there is no application listening to the port. Try to run

```
nc -l 25
```

(as root of course) and redo the scan.

If the firewall would be blocking the port, nmap would show it as filtered.

Comment: True. This is explained here: [*Port Scanning Basics*](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html).

Comment: interesting. it seems like my hosting provider closes port 25 within the routing table.

Comment: That is unlikely. Routing is (normally) layer 3, ports are layer 4. If you know a tcp-server is listening on your host on port 25, you could try a `telnet 127.0.0.1 25` to see if that works.